# Deploying Ruby on Rails Apps with Mongoid (MongoDB), Redis, Resque, Capistrano, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, capistrano, resque

I am creating a Ruby on Rails website deployed on AWS. I am running into configuration issues and I can't seem to find docs/tutorials that cover configuration of the various tools mentioned and how to set them up BOTH for ease of use in development (on localhost) and while deploying.

Right now I have a Rails app set up and I am using Bundler for all my Ruby gems.

I have two major goals.

1. Ease of development - Ideally somebody should just have to clone the repo and run 'rails server' and should be good to go. All other stuff like Redis servers, Resque workers, Mongo DB databases, should automatically be started/created.
2. Ease of deployment - Given some configuration file (like YAML files), I should be easily able to deploy to various stages by simply running 'cap production deploy' or something similar. It should automatically run all the rspec tests, and prevent deploying if something goes wrong. Once deployed it should also handle all other aspects like restarting Apache/Nginx, handling DB migrations, restarting Resque workers, etc. I know how to do this all manually, but again I am looking for a solution that will let a novice (i.e. unexperienced with my app's deployment process, not novice in general) easily be able to deploy.

I have looked at various tools/gems like Foreman, God, etc. but I am not clear on how to use them correctly and how they work in different environments like development and production.

I am looking for either docs/tutorials on how to do this or even Github repo's of Rails app that have solved these problems (preferably smaller repo's so that I don't have to wade through application specific stuff to get the information I looking for).

I am also looking for a way to monitor my Rails app. As what kind of errors are happening? how frequently are they happening? Is Splunk a good tool to do so?

Note : I am not tied down to use any of the tools mentioned above, since I am only starting to develop my website.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/Ada-Developers-Academy/daily-curriculum/blob/master/week21/wednesday/provisioning-and-deploying-to-a-vps.md) is pretty comprehensive if you want to deploy to a small EC2 instance using Capistrano and Apache.

For monitoring I'd suggest New Relic or just checking your logfiles.

However, you're going to have to be more specific about your technology questions. You're covering a lot of breadth here and going deeper into answering this would require a lengthy essay and possibly a consulting fee.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah I realize that I am asking an open-ended lengthy question. Thats why I asked for docs/tutorials and example apps that do this.

Comment: In general you should probably avoid open-ended question on SO if you want results: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Play around a little, give yourself an opportunity to run into a specific problem, google it and then ask if you don't find anything.